# Series expansion (bug in 11.2?)

Tags: bugs, series-expansion, version-11.2

The following code:

```
Series[x^2 Sqrt[1 + 1/x^4], {x, 0, 0}]
```

gives different results in Mathematica 11.0 and 11.2. In 11.0 I get the expected result

```
1+O[x]^2
```

while 11.2 gives

```
O[x]^2
```

Even worse, in Mathematica 11.2

```
Series[x^2 Sqrt[1 + 1/x^6], {x, 0, 0}]
```

also gives

```
O[x]^2
```

while in 11.0 I get

```
1/x + O[x]^1
```

Is this a known bug in 11.2? Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: In v11.2, `Limit[x^2 Sqrt[1 + 1/x^4], x -> 0]` evaluates to `1`

Comment: Despite 0 being a branch point I think this should probably not return an empty series. Provisionally treating it as a bug in 11.2. I should remark that in the absence of assumptions on `x`, `1+O[x]^2` is also not a correct result.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: sure, `1+O[x]^2` is not correct for all `x`. However, if I expand `y Sqrt[1 + 1/y^2]` v11.2 gives `y Sqrt[1/y^2]`, so for the first example in my question `x^2 Sqrt[1/x^4]` seems a reasonable answer. Furthermore, even with `Assuming [x \[Element] Reals, ... ]` I get `0` and not  `1`.

Comment: What you propose as a reasonable answer is what I'm hoping to get into the next release.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
Assuming [x \[Element] Reals && x >= 0, Series[Sqrt[1 + 1/x^4] x^2, {x, 0, 0}]]
Assuming [x \[Element] Reals && x >= 0, Series[Sqrt[1 + 1/x^6] x^2, {x, 0, 0}]]
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually assuming `x >= 0` is enough.

Comment: Or assume `x <= 0` or `x < 0 || x >= 0`